# Is it normal that Django ORM makes a DB call on every object in a List View?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

I'm facing a problem of extra DB calls to retrieve object's data.
I have a model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name="posts", on_delete=CASCADE)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name="posts", on_delete=CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField(verbose_name="Content", max_length=1300)
    liked_by = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, related_name="post_likes", blank=True)
    date_published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Date published")
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Date modified")
    is_active = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Active", default=True)
    tags = TaggableManager(blank=True, related_name="posts")
```

I am calling a View to list all Post objects (currently, there are 4) but getting 4 extra queries to `posts_post` for each entity. Is that normal behaviour to make an individual DB call on each entity in DB (not related entities but the root entities).

My View:

```
class PostListAPIView(APIView):

def get(self, request) -> Response:
    """Return a list of all posts.

    all_posts = (
            Post.objects
            .select_related("profile__specialization", "project")
            .prefetch_related(
                "tags",
                Prefetch(
                    "liked_by", queryset=Profile.objects.select_related("specialization").only(
                        "id",
                        "username",
                        "first_name",
                        "last_name",
                        "photo",
                        "specialization"
                    )
                )
            )
            .annotate(
                comments_count=Count("comments", distinct=True),
                likes_count=Count("liked_by", distinct=True)
            )
            .defer("body")
            .order_by("-date_published")
        )
    post_serializer = PostDetailDTOSerializer(all_posts, many=True)
    posts_serialized_data = post_serializer.data
    return Response(
        {
            "posts": posts_serialized_data,
        },

        status=status.HTTP_200_OK
    )
```

My query list as per DjDT:
[image]

Comment: Those extra queries with the ID specified and the 'limit 21' restraint look to me like the queries Django generates for an `exists()` call. I haven't fully internalized the details of the `Prefetch` API, so I can't absolutely say that they're not coming from it, but you might also check whether your view or template ever makes those (explicitly or via an `if post:` style check).

Comment: I don't have any `exist()` checks (explicitly or via an `if post:`) in my code related to view lists all `Post` objects.

Comment: Is this from looking at the queries using the Django-debug-toolbar? It could be that those queries are from the browsable api

Comment: Yes, it is. But strange that I have plenty of a models (Comments as well) but all excesive DB calls were successfully removed by meaning of `select_related()` and `prefetch_related()`.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using pagination and ListModelMixin in your Viewset.

Because of Pagination, you are getting limit 21 constraint which is not an issue here.

`ListModelMixin` is at the fault here as it is triggering `n+1` problem. You can override ListModelMixin as per your case.

Please provide your viewset also for more clarity.

Comment: All my views are just a custom class inherits from APIView with Paginator class manually configured. And I have an issue only with this mode by some reason. Just let me know sharing some extra info will help.

Comment: @Antony_K Can you provide your listing logic that is in your viewset, so that I can see what is happening ?

Comment: I've replaced a DB call by complete View where I face this problem. The code was simplified as I have multi-layer project structure and there are many methods call from the other source.